# GoogleColab　Key input method

Tags: google-colaboratory

When the command is executed and input is requested to the output
How do I enter?

I'd like to install cuda
I can ask for input while I can not respond
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `-y`, e.g.,

```
apt-get -y install [packagename]
```

But, be aware that if you're using a GPU backend, CUDA should be installed by default.

Comment: Unknown option: y
!wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.1/Prod/local_installers/cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux
!sh cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux -y